# Format table names differently than column names in dropdown?

Tags: redquerybuilder

This may seem like a silly question, but it's taking me way too long to find the answer, so I'm hoping I can get some help here.

If I'm understanding correctly, the sample [RedQueryBuilder](http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/) formats the table names that are related to the initial table in "Proper Case", while the columns of the initial table are all caps.  This is wonderfully helpful in distinguishing the tables from the columns.

[image: RedQueryBuilder dropdown list screenshot]

Developers at my place of work (who are not currently available to ask) implemented the RedQueryBuilder in one of their web apps, and somehow, the table names AND the column names are all "Proper Case."  This makes it impossible to tell which are tables and which are columns.  I've scoured the code, searched through any available CSS, stepped through the app in the JS debugger, etc, to try to figure out how to format the list of tables + columns the way it's done in the original, but it's taking forever, and I can't seem to find it.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be fantastic!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In the meta data that is sent to the client you should be able to send "name" and "label" values. The "name" is used when reading/writing the SQL and the "label" is displayed to the user.

You should be able to control it there.